# От чего зависит обособление оборотов вида "как завороженный","как зачарованный"?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, сравнительный-оборот

Почему разная пунктуация в сходных по структуре предложениях? Как автор делает выбор, обособляя или не обособляя оборот?

1. (1) *Как заворожённый, смотрю в экран висящего в углу телевизора*.
   (2) *Как завороженный выслушал я известие.*
2. (3) *Крылов смотрел как завороженный.* (4) *Я следил за ней как заворожённый.*

Это фразеологизм или устойчивое выражение (какое название более правильное)?  Влияет ли статус сравнительного оборота на его обособление?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142502/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Нашёл у Розенталя в списке устойчивых выражений: *слушал как завороженный; смотрел как зачарованный*. Неожиданный поворот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - [Лопатин, Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации, 2006. Знаки препинания при сравнительных оборотах, §88, а)](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-6%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A788).

2,3,4 - [Лопатин, §90, г)](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-6%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A790). Для 3 подходит и а), потому что сказуемое конкретизируется. Но итог один, без запятой.

---

*Это фразеологизм или устойчивое выражение (какое название более правильное)?*

Нет короткого термина. Это словосочетание, которое может играть разную синтаксическую роль. В предложении есть основа и ВЧП. У ВЧП возможны как бы 3 стадии обособленности:

1. Необособленный ВПЧ. Синтакс.связь с главным - подчинение.
2. Обособленный ВЧП. Синтакс.связь - полупредикативная, со сказуемым (прич. и дееп.обороты, обстоятельства, дополнения). + Определения, приложения + уточнения, пояснения (плавающий статус, во многом схожи с присоединением).
3. Присоединение. Синтакс.связь - присоединение.

Первые - часть простого предложения. Вторые - аналоги придаточного (часто можно в него трансформировать). Третьи - аналоги отдельного предложения (не часть сложного!).

Как это применить на практике?

- Первую группу невозможно удалить без потери смысла (не смысла вообще, как считывают обыватели, так-то можно хоть из предлогов предложение сделать, а смысла вот этого именно высказывания). Обособленные обычно можно.
- Распространенность способствует обособлению. Если ВЧП при общем главном больше двух, почти наверняка обособленный ВЧП тоже будет.

Это общий принцип. За остальным - только справочники по пунктуации, где универсального решения нет, но совсем ошибиться не дадут.

Об этом можно посмотреть, например: [Солганик "Русский язык и культура речи. Синтаксис", 2018](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZSQaHf3EL2SD-wkLyBPxpUT00EMf4Mwv/view), главы 11 (Обособленные ВЧП) и 14 (Присоединительные конструкции).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но мне нужно сделать выбор  и объяснить именно эти четыре КОНКРЕТНЫЕ предложения, а еще указать правило Розенталя,  на которое я могла бы сослаться.   И еще правильно назвать этот оборот.  Представьте, что я редактирую рукопись.  Вы можете выбрать,и объяснить знак и дать ссылку? Допустим, это требует от меня редактор, который не особенно разбирается в теме. Он должен быть уверен, что ответ правильный.

Comment: Апдейт, со ссылкой.

Comment: Все обороты имеют значение уподобления (как будто завороженный,  метафора).  Но при этом они могут обособляться или нет. Не обособляются, если на первый план выступает обстоятельственное значение, а как это узнать. Какие-либо проверки (Т.п. и т.д.) вряд ли возможны. Кроме того, очевидно, что обособление связано со структурой и распространенностью предложения. но здесь все практически одинаково.

Comment: Ну, вам бы определиться с целью вопроса) Я даю механизм, вы требуете правил. Я даю правила, вы требуете объяснить логику. Редакторы, кстати, с правилами не спорят.

Comment: Эти правила не подходят. Сравним пару: Тропинка вьется как змея (змеёй). Тропинка, как змея, вьется среди скал. Т.п. подходит к обоим случаям, но на решение во втором варианте не влияет, там важна распространенность.  Все эти проверки никогда не вызывали у меня доверия,  И вы моего редактора не знаете, теперь он точно меня уволит))  Он бывший математик и любит точность.

Comment: Нет, не подходит к обоим случаям. Но математик это не увидит, разумеется.

Comment: Почему не подходит? Тропинка, как змея (змеей), вьется среди скал.  Но оборот обособлен.

Comment: Пожалуй, на этом дискуссию закончим, вопрос оказался нерешаемым (тонкая это материя, с помощью одних правил не решишь). Всем большое спасибо!